# Saving a webpage as PDF using Python?

Tags: python, xml, pdf, flask

I'm trying to save/export a full web page result to PDF using python

I have generated a webpage which contains some calculation results and a comment section which is accompanied with an "Export to PDF" button.

What I did so far is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request, Response
app = Flask(__name__)




@app.route('/result', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def viewResult():
    if request.method == 'POST':

            if 'export' in request.form:

                    x = "XMLXMLXMLXML"

                    request.headers['Content-Type: application/pdf']
                    request.headers["Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='x.pdf'"]

                    return x


            return ''
else:
            global result
    result = 'xml'
            html = ''
            html += '<html>'
            html += '<body>'
            html += '<p>Result</p>'
            html += '<a  href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/">Back</a>'
            html += '<div>'
            html += '<b>Result:</b>'
            html += '<textarea name="result" readonly>' + result + '</textarea>'
            html += '<form method="POST">'
            html += '<br>'
            html += '<textarea name="content" placeholder="Enter a comment"></textarea>'
            html += '<p></p>'
            html += '<input type="submit" name="export" value="Save">'
            html += '</form>'
            html += '</div>'
            html += '</body>'
            html += '</html>'
            return html
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I've tested/researched a couple of methods so far but none seem to make it work in my case.
Please excuse my coding logic. I'm not a python expert :x

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: a little  wrong ! File not a web-browser element. Need a html  element inside file as object. Can write as base64  without any limitation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But could you clarify further? I don't think I understood what you mean.

Comment: Your question is probably a bit broad as each export format is so different. You'll probably be better off limiting your question to a specific format and going from there.

Comment: yeah, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the popular, open-source [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) which you can call externally in Python by simply passing in *.html* file and *.pdf* file names. Simply, download its executable and run command lines with it. Plus you can specify page size (`-s A4`)and orientation arguments (`-O landscape`). Also, wkhtmltopdf works great with page-rendering CSS like `page-break-before: always`, `page-break-inside: avoid !important;`, etc.

Below is an example with screenshots using posted html string. Integrate the method into your app's code base.

```
import os
...

result = 'xml'

html = ''
html += '<html>'
html += '<body>'
html += '<p>Result</p>'
html += '<a  href="http://127.0.0.1:5000/">Back</a>'
html += '<div>'
html += '<b>Result:</b>'
html += '<textarea name="result" readonly>' + result + '</textarea>'
html += '<form method="POST">'
html += '<br>'
html += '<textarea name="content" placeholder="Enter a comment"></textarea>'
html += '<p></p>'
html += '<input type="submit" name="export" value="Save">'
html += '</form>'
html += '</div>'
html += '</body>'
html += '</html>'

# OUTPUT HTML PAGE
file = open('WebPage.html', 'w')
file.write(html)
file.close()

# OUTPUT PDF PAGE
os.system('/path/to/wkhtmltopdf /path/to/WebPage.html /path/to/WebPage.pdf')
```

**HTML File**
[image: Web Page HTML]

**PDF File**
[image: Web Page PDF]

Comment: Thank you very much Parfait! I'll be testing it now.